# How to read C# variable each second from javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#

In my file1.aspx I have the following code:

```
...
<script>
        funct();
        setInterval('funct()', 4000);
        function funct() {
            var list= $.connection.listHub;
            list.client.logMessage = function (msg) {
              method(msg);
          };
          $.connection.hub.start();
          $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
              $.connection.hub.start();
            }, 500); // Restart connection after 0.5 seconds.
          });
          method("<%= this.var %>"); //here is the variable
        };
</script>
...
```

The problem is that this variable (this.var) is changing each 4 seconds. In my file1.aspx.cs file, this variable is changing in a while-true loop each 4 seconds and Javascript is reading only the first value of var. There is way to update var value in Javascript?

Comment: Use ajax to call server side function.

Comment: For me using SignalR to update data every 4 seconds sounds like wrong design. Your server should beacon this variable every 4 seconds so that your clients get this as SignalR message. Otherwise, it is not any better than AJAX polling, just use AJAX. I may be wrong

Comment: Or push the new value to your client when it's value changed - SignalR could be used for this.

Comment: Thanks you for your message. Can you recommend me something more speciffic? I have no used ajax yet.

Comment: A `file1.aspx.cs` should not and can not have a `while(true)` loop. Threading in asp.net will take some more study.

Answer (score 0):

As [Access Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1099716/access-denied) has already pointed out, if you know that the variable is changing each 4 seconds (not just occasionally) - it's reasonable to use HTTP requests instead of WebSockets (or signalR hub connection - that can use WebSockets under the hood).

As you're already using jQuery, you could use [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function and call it in a loop using e.g. [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

The example from the [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) page with my additions:

```
// sets the timer, 4000 ms = 4 seconds
var variableInterval = setInterval(doVariableRequest, 4000);

// call to stop the "timer"
function stopVariableInterval() {
    clearInterval(variableInterval);
}

function doVariableRequest() {
    // your API method URL - could use ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI/Core project to implement it.
    var variableUrl = "http://localhost:4242/Variables/Current";
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: variableUrl, 
    })
    .done(function( variable ) {
      // process your variable - e.g. assign its value to some UI element
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Dmitry. I'm searching info about Ajax because like I said before, I have no used Ajax yet. I'm so confused right now. I can't find an example which can serve me...

Comment: Thanks you again! I'm having one problem. What you wrote as "Current" is the function which return my variable, right? But if I don't define this function like static, doesn't work. And if I define it like static, i get an error in return line because the function is static...

Comment: ajax makes HTTP calls, that can be processed by a web application. Such application can be an ASP.NET MVC/WebAPI/Core project - please google for examples how to write/ implement them. They will eventually be launched as a web server and be queried from your javascript code using $.ajax function. You need to implement a back-end endpoint (i.e. "http://localhost:4242/Variables/Current") - please investigate the topic e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: That's not te problem Dmitry. My problem is with my variable that's not static...

Comment: I have read a lot of posts and is impossible to make ajax calls to non static methods..So I don't understand how can I get what I want with Ajax...